# how to get the count of rows from adynamically created html page,using c#

Tags: c#, html, aspose

I have Some html templates for generating reports.

First i am generating an html page by merging these templates in some order and i get a Final Html page as a string as my output, this is done using c#.

Later i will convert this html string to PDF , by converting it into an aspose document and then to pdf. this part done using c#.net and aspose.

What i need is, each page consists of around 20 rows.I need to set like this. each page should contains only 20 rows, (these each row have inner tables and rows too). but i want to count based on the main row and in a page it should be 20 only.

so from the html page or string formatted html page, is there any way to set a pagebreak after every 20 main rows.
i am using only aspose.word and not aspose.pdf.

after every 20 main table rows, i want to add page break.
i have generated this html page as a string, so is there any way to check the count of main table row and add page break in that string.

Comment: Didn't really understand the question, do you want to split it every 20 rows where a row represents where the new line character is, or every 20 main table rows?

Comment: On every 20 main table rows, i want to add a page break.

Comment: You want to do what? Put in a "page break", in the html? What does that mean, spilt into 2 different pages or? You can't really do "page breaks" in html.

Comment: i have generated this html page as a string, so is there any way to check the count of main table row and add page break in that string.

Comment: yes, split the page into two, by adding page break, i want only 20 main table row in one page

Comment: [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) will help in what you want to do, but you'll break you HTML if you do what you have in mind. I'd suggest you make a template page grab 20 rows at a time and inject them in it. Maybe add an example so we get a better idea of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you query is not very clear. Do you need to include the page break in the HTML string. That might be very complex in your scenario as you will need to check for the row tags and after a specific count you will need to include a break. This will become difficult even more when you use child tables as well.

If you are using Aspose.Words for .NET and want to [split the tables](http://goo.gl/hAz6YY) to new pages in a word document, you can check the following code:

```
//Open document and create DocumentBuilder
Document doc = new Document(@"d:\\data\\Tables.docx");

DocumentBuilder buildr = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

//Get table from document
Table tab = doc.FirstSection.Body.Tables[0];

//We should split our table and insert breaks between parts of table.
int count = 0;
Table clone = (Table)tab.Clone(false);

int total = tab.Rows.Count % 20;

while (tab.Rows.Count  > 1)
{
    if (tab.Rows.Count > total)
    {
        clone.AppendChild(tab.FirstRow);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
    if (count == 19 )
    {
        //Insert empty paragraph after original table
        Paragraph par = new Paragraph(doc);
        tab.ParentNode.InsertBefore(par, tab);

        //Insert newly created table after paragraph
        par.ParentNode.InsertBefore(clone, par);

        //Move document builder cursor to the paragraph
        buildr.MoveTo(par);

        //And insert PageBreak also you can use SectionBreakNewPage
        buildr.InsertBreak(BreakType.PageBreak);
        count = 0;
        clone = (Table)tab.Clone(false);

    }
    else
    {
        count = count + 1;
    }
}

//Save output document
doc.Save(@"d:\\data\\out.docx");
```

P.S. I am social media developer at Aspose.